# question regarding filed in C - how to scan print get

Tags: c, file, printf, scanf, fgetc

I am trying to answer a question I got for an interview, but not sure about the answer:

We define that action Y is the inclusion of action X, if X is defined only for some of the cases where Y is defined and for all cases where X is defined, Y's behavior is completely identical to that of X.

What is the **wrong** claim?

```
printf is a generalization of fprintf


scanf is a generalization of fscanf


All allegations are true


getchar is a generalization of fgetc


gets is the inclusion of fgets
```

Comment: All "generalization" claims seems wrong (the opposite should be true).

Comment: "What is the wrong claim?" is confusing me, because it seems to imply that there is exactly one (though I'd tolerate to say the one true is the one that all are true, if that were the case). Also confusing is to me the elaborate definition of the term "inclusion", which contrast weirdly with the fact that the term is then used only once. So I get the impression that the question was either faulty as you were asked it, or you made mistakes by writing it down from memory or, an that is not the most unlikely explanation, the actual question in the interview was "Do you spot the error?".

Answer (score 3):

> `printf` is a generalization of `fprintf`

no, `fprintf` is the generalization of `printf` / `printf` is exactly equivalent to `fprintf(stdout, ...)`

> `scanf` is a generalization of `fscanf`

no, just like above, `fscanf` is the generalization of `scanf` for *any* stream handle.

> All allegations are true

most certainly not!

> `getchar` is a generalization of `fgetc`

no, `fgetc` is a generalization of `getchar`

> `gets` is the inclusion of `fgets`

no, `gets` has been removed from the standard altogether, and even when it was there, it did not even work like `fgets` at all, as it removes the newline character, which was not done by `fgets`, therefore it doesn't work like `fgets` in all the cases where `fgets` work.

Therefore each allegation is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

All of the claims are completely wrong. all the functions you have mentioned above are a **private case** for the function on the right.

e.g. `printf` is a private case of `fprintf`, where the file descriptor in `fprintf` is the standard output.

quoting from man7.org

```
int fprintf(FILE *restrict stream, const char *restrict format, ...);
```

> The fprintf() function shall place output on the named output stream.
> The printf() function shall place output on the standard output
> stream stdout.

So `fprintf` is the inclusion of `printf` (printf is defined only for some of the cases where `fprintf` is defined and for all cases where printf  is defined).

In a similar way, all the functions that mentioned in the question. keep looking in man.7 links are below:

[fgetc](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html)
[fgets](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3p.html#:%7E:text=The%20fgets()%20function%20shall,terminated%20with%20a%20null%20byte.)
[fscanf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fscanf.3p.html)